# Inserting elements into DOM, basing position on timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, binary-search

I have a JSON object with an array of "updates", where each "update" consists of a timestamp and a message:

```
updates : {
    {
        timestamp : 1329505671,
        text : 'test1'
    },
    {
        timestamp : 1329505783,
        text : 'test2'
    }
}
```

Using jQuery, I parse these into DOM elements and insert them at the same level, in the order they were received. They are presorted based on my SQL query in the AJAX call.

Now, I have a recurring ajax call that checks for new updates. If an update is found, it needs to insert it into the DOM, in the appropriate position.

I cannot assume that these updates will always be the newest update in the list, so, I need a way to find which DOM update to insert the new update after.

I had planned on creating a `Map<int, DOMUpdate>` of sorts (`updates[timestamp] = DOMUpdate` in Javascript).

There are a couple flaws with this plan, though:

1. I'd have to find/create a fast binary search algorithm for finding
   which timestamp to put the update after.
2. I couldn't have duplicate timestamps.

So my question is if anyone else has done something similar, and if so, how did you approach it? Please let me know if I'm being unclear in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just find the first element that has a timestamp that is greater than it and append it before that element. If none are found, it is the newest and should be appended at the start/end depending on the order you are posting them(newest first or last).

```
var appended = false;
$(collection).each(function(){
  var timestamp = $(this).data("timestamp"); // replace with your code
  if (timestamp < obj.timestamp) {
    $(this).before(buildNewElement(obj));
    appended = true;
    return false;
  }
});
if (!appended) {
  $(collection).last().after(buildNewElement(obj));
}
```

Obviously this is just a concept, you will need to modify it to fit your code/requirements.

Edit:

If you stored your data in an array of objects, and then added objects to that array as more were received, you could sort that array on the timestamp and then append the new objects based on the index after sorting. You would have to add a property to the newly received objects, and then remove that property as you loop through all of the objects and append only those that have that property.

Comment: Yeah, this is an option, ofc, but I wanted it to be a bit faster than a linear search. I guess it should perform fast enough.

Comment: A linear search is pretty much the only way to do it. You have to first find the first element that is newer than it, and append it before it. You could do it with a filter method too, but i don't expect it to be any faster as it still has to search through them. I updated the answer to show how to exit out of the `.each()`

Comment: I guess linear is actually the way to go, since although the update might not be the newest, it is most certainly going to be in the upper half of updates. So it is going to be at least as fast as binary search. Thanks for the input.